# How to save two forms in one model in Django?

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-models, django-forms

I have two Django forms of the same model in the same view, so when I try to save them I get two objects of the model and my goal is to get one single object with the data of both forms.

I've tried to save both forms separately, which lead to creating two objects. Also, I've thought of saving one form and then updating the second one but I just don't know how to do that.

```
    if request.method == 'POST':
        animal_form_required = AddAnimalFormRequired(data=request.POST)
        animal_form_optional = AddAnimalFormOptional(data=request.POST)
        if animal_form_required.is_valid() and animal_form_optional.is_valid():

            animal_required = animal_form_required.save(commit=False)
            animal_required.save()

            animal_optional = animal_form_optional.save()
            animal_optional.save()

            return render(...)
```

`animal_required` and `animal_optional` are the two forms and `animal` is the model. Both forms have different attributes of the animal. After doing this, I get two objets of `animal`: one with the `animal_required`attributes and one with the `animal_optional` attributes. How can I get one single object of `animal`with all the attributes?
Thanks so much in advance!

Comment: As a matter of interest, why do you have two separate forms rather than just adding optional fields to a single form?

Comment: @daniel-roseman I have two forms because I want one of the forms to be hidden INSIDE a ```div``` with a **collapse** class of Bootstrap so it's displayed when I press a button. [link](https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap4/bootstrap_collapse.asp)

Answer (score 0):

You could save the first `Form`, and then pass the created object to the second form like this:

```
if request.method == 'POST':
    animal_form_required = AddAnimalFormRequired(data=request.POST)
    animal_form_optional = AddAnimalFormOptional(data=request.POST)
    if animal_form_required.is_valid() and animal_form_optional.is_valid():

        created_animal = animal_form_required.save()

        animal_optional.instance = created_animal
        animal_optional.save()

        return render(...)
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response! I did what you told me,
but it would create one object of ```animal``` with the ```animal_form_required``` attributes and ignore the ```animal_form_optional``` ones.